# Problems with running MongoDB when JUnit tests are ran

Tags: java, mongodb, junit, pom.xml

I need mongoDB to run automatically when my JUnit tests are ran,and then to stop when the tests are complete. I've tried using the maven mongoDB plugin but mongoDB doesn't seem to run. Any help?

Comment: You unittests should mock out the communication to the real database in the first place (unless they are just application tests done with the JUnit framework...).

Comment: @TimothyTruckle if you're talking about mocking out the mongo driver then please don't do this.  Here is an article on why you shouldn't do that https://jaxenter.com/testing-the-database-layer-119366.html

Comment: The articles arguments are valid when you test behavior *in the database*. When you are (*unit-*) testing the business logic outside the database, then you really should mock the database access.

Comment: I doubt why your `UnitTest` should include testing something related to the DB at the first place. Even if you need to do that mocking should suffice the need.

Comment: @TimothyTruckle at that point you're mocking your Repository layer, you still shouldn't be mocking the db api

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use embed.mongo for this: https://github.com/flapdoodle-oss/de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo

It basically starts an embedded mongo db in the current jvm.

You can start it using the `@BeforeAll` / `@Before` clause and stop it afterwards and everything will be cleaned up.

Spring Boot has a auto-configuration built in so you only need to add a dependency to embed.mongo: http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-mongo-embedded

Otherwise you can use the documentation on Github to set up your own embedded mongo db.

Answer (score 0):

If you are just unit testing, you should try to mock up the database integration.  However, I had to deal with this at one time and needed to test the integration between Mongo/Java project.  The Mongo plugin was not working for me, either.  Here are two options that I tried that, and maybe they will help:

Option 1 (w/ Docker): In my build and deploy stack (Maven, Jenkins, Docker), the easiest thing for me to do was to start a Mongo container as a pre-build step, run the build with integration environment configured settings, and shut down the container as a post build step.  Furthermore, if you have specific data you need to test, you can build a container that has that data.

Option 2 (just Maven/Mongo): in Maven's`pre-integration-tests` lifecycle phase, make a call to the operating system using [Maven exec plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/) to start Mongo.  Run your tests, and make sure the ones that require Mongo are run during the `integration-test` phase.  Then close Mongo down in the `post-integration-test` phase.  Depending on your tests, this might be tricky if they alter the state of your Mongo instance.  If that is an issue, you could write some scripts to reinitialize/destroy Mongo, and call those scripts in the phases mentioned above.

[Maven lifecycle reference](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html)